# Just upgraded a site from 2.4 to 2.7.2, get errors when trying to view front-end freemember forms

Tags: error, freemember, expresso

Has Freemember been updated to work with EE 2.7.2? This is the error I get when trying to access a freemember form on the front end...

```
Error

Unable to load the requested class: safecracker_lib
```

Was using FreeMember 2.0.1 and upgraded to 2.3.0.

Comment: For future reference, can you update this post with what version of Freeform you were using, and the version of Freeform you upgraded to? Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were using 2.4 you probably need to update FreeMember to the latest version to address changes in EE for the 2.7.x releases. Safecracker is now part of the channel module.

You can download the latest version at https://github.com/expressodev/freemember

Answer (score 1):

bah, had an older version of Freemember installed. Installed new version and things seem to be working ok so far.

Answer (score 0):

When I google "ExpressionEngine Freemember" I get [this page](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember), which shows the last update to this plugin being in May 2013. So I'm guessing that, no, it hasn't.

Comment: The official source for Freemember versions is https://github.com/expressodev/freemember so that page is a bit out of date. It's still under active development/support though :)